# Sum of two cochain complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology

I've recently started studying Algebraic Topology and I'm struggling with something:

Let $\Bbbk$ be a commutative ring with $1$. Define $C^{q}(X) := \text{Hom}_{\Bbbk}(C_{q}(x), \Bbbk)$ where $C_{q}$ is a chain complex. In singular homology, $C_{q}$ is the free abelian group generated by singular $q$-simplices in a topological space $X$.

Given $\psi \in C^{q}(X)$ and $\phi \in C^{p}(X)$, what does $\psi + \phi$ means? Is it the sum in $\Bbbk$? I'm having trouble with this.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Nothing. That does not mean anything because those two elements which you are trying to sum are in *different* groups.

Comment: I guess it must be a typo. Thanks :). And if both are in the same group, what does it means?

Comment: If A and B are abelian groups and $f$, $g:A\to B$ are group homomorphisms, what does $f+g$ mean?

Comment: $(f+g)(x) := f(x) + g(x)$ for all $x \in A$. So you're just adding the elements of $C_{q}$?

Comment: It could be short hand for the cup product? so you would get an element of the $p+q$ chains. See hatcher's 3rd chapter for an explanation of the cup product.Though it is a product rather than a sum so would be strange to use this additive notation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A singular cochain of dimension $q$ is simply an $\Bbbk$-linear homomorphism.

Like you said, if $f, g: A \longrightarrow B$ are group homomorphisms, then $$(f+g)(x) := f(x) + g(x)$$

for all $x \in A$.